# How to test whether SSH has passwordless access without prompting for password?

Tags: shell-script, ssh

I'm writing an unattended shell script that sets up a new server. Since I may run it multiple times, I want to check whether passwordless SSH access has already been set up. A command like

`ssh newhost.example.com /bin/true`

will exit successfully if the access exists, but if not, it will hang waiting for a password to be entered.

Is there a way to turn off the possibility of password access for such a command so that it will quickly fail if passwordless access is not yet set up?

Comment: I assume you're referring to user-level public key authentication, and not host-based authentication?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes, that's what I had in mind. The overall goal is not to hang such a script on a password prompt, but to return a success/failure as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To tell `ssh` that you only want to use public key authentication, use the [`PreferredAuthentications` configuration option](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config).

Interactively:

```
ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey newhost.example.com /bin/true
```

Or in the `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
# or Host *.example.com, or Host *
Host newhost.example.com
  PreferredAuthentications=publickey
```

Comment: Interestingly, I couldn't get my openssh client to honor `-o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no`

Comment: This is better answer to the question than mine because it accounts for `keyboard-interactive`, another possible password-prompting mode. Whitelist vs. my blacklist.

Answer (score 4):

You can turn off the `PasswordAuthentication` option:

`ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no newhost.example.com /bin/true`

This does not prompt for a password and quickly returns exit code `255` when passwordless access is denied.

Comment: There's no such thing as a negative exit code.  exit codes are an integer between 0 and 255.  The exit code of this use-case is actually 255; not -255.

Comment: there's also "keyboard-interactive", which is another way of prompting for a password.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4256 extends https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4252 by adding keyboard-interactive as an authentication method.

Answer (score 1):

With `ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no newhost.example.com /bin/true` you still risk the chance of hitting an interactive question:

```
$ ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no newhost.example.com /bin/true
The authenticity of host 'newhost.example.com (a.b.c.d)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:<fingerprint>.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

A better option, IMHO, is to run ssh in BatchMode:

```
$ ssh -o BatchMode=yes newhost.example.com /bin/true
Host key verification failed.
$ echo $?
255
```

If you have ssh passwordless login configured and working, ssh would not need to check the fingerprint and you should see it working.

Comment: "If you have ssh passwordless login configured and working" ... Isn't that the point here, to check whether it is indeed configured and working? For example, your key is added to new VMs as part of initialisation, and you're testing that, in which case it should work once the host key is accepted.

Comment: Exactly. But my point was that the test should not end at an interactive prompt. So compare running the test against a server with and one without passwordless ssh configure. If you only specify "-o PreferredAuthentications=publickey" you will likely end up with being prompted "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?", while if you add "-o BatchMode=yes" you won't get prompted.

Comment: You won't get prompted, but you won't test that which was meant to be tested either. `StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new` would be what I'd go for in this case, if I didn't feel inclined to verify the key myself.

Comment: This is the best answer imo, the other ones end up prompting me for a password.