# How to restrict ssh client to connect with SSH certificate only and issue an error instead an interactive login prompt?

Tags: ssh, login

Imagine the following situation: you want to login with a SSH certificate to a remote system, but as it does not accept the certificate, you get an interactive prompt.

Like this:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking no -t -i /tmp/.ssh-cert username@host whoami
username@host's password:
```

What happens then, the interactive prompt remains there for some time until the remote host would decide to drop the connection.

Question: how to automatically recognize this situation, so that instead of idling with the prompt, local SSH client issues an error?

Comment: perhaps https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/472822/117549 ? (related to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/474781/exit-from-script-if-ssh-prompts-for-password)

Comment: thank you - ```-o PasswordAuthentication=no``` does the job for me!